# Why my sidebar reloads the page when i clicked it instead of hide my menu? Angular 8

Tags: angular

Everytime I call a component that contains the sidebar and i clicked to it, reloads my page and redirects me to path: ''.

I dont know if im worng with my routes or if im missing something.

Here are the routes, the code where i call my components, and one example of component. Thanks beforehand.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
{path: '', component: InicioComponent},
{path: 'historia', component: HistoriaComponent},
{path: 'arquitectura', component: ArquitecturaComponent},
{path: 'turismo', component: TurismoComponent},
{path: 'hoteles', component: HotelesComponent}
];
```

**panel.component.html** Where I call my components that contains the sidebar

```
<div id="app">
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
 <!-- AQUI VA EL HEADER -->
 **<router-outlet name="headerOutlet"></router-outlet>**
  <div class="main-sidebar">
    <aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="index.html">Styler</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-brand sidebar-brand-sm">
        <a href="index.html">S</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="menu-header">Menú</li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown active"  >
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['datos'],headerOutlet: ['datosheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span>Mis Datos</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['clientes'],headerOutlet: ['clientesheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span>Clientes</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['departamentos'],headerOutlet: ['departamentosheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i><span>Departamentos</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['productos'],headerOutlet: ['productosheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Productos</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['servicios'],headerOutlet: ['serviciosheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-cut"></i><span>Servicios</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['citas'],headerOutlet: ['citasheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i><span>Citas</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['pos'],headerOutlet: ['posheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-store"></i><span>Punto de Venta</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['historial'],headerOutlet: ['historialheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-history"></i><span>Historial</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { panelOutlet: ['productividad'],headerOutlet: ['productividadheader'] } }]" class=""><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i><span>Productividad</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="main-content">
    <section class="section">
      <router-outlet name="panelOutlet"></router-outlet>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

**citas-header.component.html** One example of my components, the rest are the same in structure.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-navbar">
<form class="form-inline mr-auto">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-3">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="sidebar" class="nav-link nav-link-lg"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="#" data-toggle="search" class="nav-link nav-link-lg d-sm-none"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li> -->
    </ul>
    <div class="search-element">
        <!-- <input type="search" class="text form-control" id="inputBuscarCliente" placeholder="Ingrese los apellidos del cliente" />
    <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button> -->
    </div>
</form>



<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-list-toggle"><a href="" title="Citas"  class="nav-link nav-link-lg beep"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></li>

    <li class="dropdown dropdown-list-toggle">
    <a class="nav-link nav-link-lg beep" href="" title="Enviar recordatorios">
        <div style="margin-top: -6px;margin-bottom: -4px;margin-left: -6px;width: 10px;height: 10px;font-size: 13px;"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></div><i class="fas fa-share"></i>
        <span class="badge"></span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-lg nav-link-user">
            <img alt="image" src="" class="rounded-circle mr-1">
            <div class="d-sm-none d-lg-inline-block">Hola</div>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <div class="dropdown-title">Opciones</div>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item has-icon tooltips">
                <i class="far fa-user"></i> Perfil
            </a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item has-icon tooltips">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i> Estilistas
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item has-icon tooltips submenuTemplate" href="javascript"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAcercaDe">
                <i class="fas fa-info"></i> Acerca de
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger tooltips salirswal">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Cerrar sesión
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the router where u click is not exist , automatically u will be redirect to the main page 
try to check the true route

Answer (score 0):

remove href attribut and use routerLink instead.